# What happens to vanity URL on careers after subscription expires?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, vanity-url

After your careers subscription expires, will the vanity URL be released and allowed to go to whomever requests it next, or is it permanently attached to your account, waiting for your next job search phase?

Preferably once it's assigned it would be nice to always have it there, but you might run into an issue where, over decades, vanity URLs become increasingly arcane due to the non-expiration of older, unused URLs.

A nice middle ground might be, "We reserve it for you for X year(s) beyond the last subscription," but I understand that careers has a responsibility to provide the best service to paying members, which may include a larger, unencumbered pool of vanity URLs.

At any rate, please explicitly state the policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vanity URLs should be valid forever, and as Timothy pointed out, are not tied to payment in any way -- they are totally free.

We might, however, cause **unused "reserved" vanity URLs to expire after a certain amount of time** if you are not actively using them, e.g., you never publish your CV.

Answer (score 8):

[Publishing your CV](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/free-public-careers-cvs/) and the vanity URL that goes with it is free. What costs money is filing the CV so that it will be included in the search results for employers.

> Publish CV: free, public CVs for any
> working programmer who wants one, at
> the URL of their choice.
>
> File CV: subscribe for a nominal fee, and
> make your private CV visible to and
> searchable by hiring managers
>
> Public CVs can be made visible, with full
> privacy controls, at the custom URL of
> your choice.

Comment: Ah.  I obviously should have read the blog post from yesterday that clears this right up.  Carry on then!